# How to reduce the number of vertical lines in a KendoUI line graph?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-ui

Using KendoUI I need to replace an exiting DotNet Charting line graph with KendoUI. Is there a way to reduce the number of vertical lines in the KendoUI line graph?

The following is an Image of the chart I'm replacing and my KendoUi chart:

[image]

This is my Kendo UI script:

```
jQuery('#divChart').kendoChart({ 
   title: { 
        text: "Overall Score out of 100", 
        align: "left", font: "18px Arial, Verdana, sans-serif" 
   },
   seriesDefaults: { type: "line" },
   legend: { position: "bottom" }, 
   tooltip: {  visible: true,  format: "{0}%" },
   valueAxis: 
   { 
        min: 70, 
        max: 95, 
        plotBands: 
        [
             { from: 70, to: 75, color: "#EDF5FF" },
             { from: 80, to: 85, color: "#EDF5FF" },
             { from: 90, to: 95, color: "#EDF5FF" }
        ]
    },
    series: 
    [ 
         { 
              name: "Some Product", 
              color:"004990", 
              tooltip: 
              { 
                   visible: true, 
                   template: "<b>Some Product</b><br/>Current Score: #= value # " 
               }, 
               data: [88.27,89.03,89.37,89.65,90.79,90.62,89.67,89.8,89.84,88.99,88.84,88.99,88.15,88.04,87.34,86.95,86.88,86.84,87.07,86.85,86.91,87.31,87.65,87.77,88.21,88.12,88.15,88.62,88.4,88.02,87.9,88.26,88.22,88.2,88.06,88,88.47,88.43,89.09,89.01,88.74,88.98,88.91,89.19,89.61,89.8,89.99,89.48,88.91,88.57,88.74,88.84,89.41,89.46,89.81,89.74,89.75,89.77,89.29,89.52,89.34] 
        },  
        { 
             name: "Some Market Segment", 
             color:"da7633", 
             tooltip: 
             { 
                 visible: true, 
                 template: "<b>Some Market Segment</b><br/>Current Score: #= value # " 
              }, 
              data: [79.47,79.52,79.34,79.91,80.1,79.2,79.01,78.97,78.95,78.83,78.81,78.01,77.63,77.66,76.53,74.87,75.22,75.74,75.12,74.73,74.89,74.78,74.92,74.95,74.67,74.57,75.15,75.32,75.01,74.2,73.82,73.78,72.77,72.76,71.8,71.81,72.13,72.46,72.24,72.46,72.49,72.98,73.34,74.01,74.13,74.3,74.4,74.25,73.81,73.52,73.59,73.49,73.41,73.51,73.72,73.27,74.23,73.99,73.97,73.83,73.79] } ], 
               categoryAxis:
               { 
                   labels: { rotation: -45 }, 
                   categories: [,,,,,,,,,,2008,,,,,,,,,,,,2009,,,,,,,,,,,,2010,,,,,,,,,,,,2011,,,,,,,,,,,,2012,,] 
                }
```

});

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reducing the number of major grid lines is not possible in the current version.

The axes support `skip` and `step` options, but only for the labels:

```
categoryAxis: {
    labels: {
        step: 2 // Render every second label
    }
}
```

We plan to extend this functionality to the major grid lines and ticks soon.

In addition, a true Date axis is also in the works. It will support common scenarios, such as this out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for the step suggestion. This fixes an issue i'm having with with the tool tips but has no effect on the Major grid lines. It's the grid lines issue I'm trying to solve here.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
    majorGridLines: {

         visible: false
    }
```

inside your `categoryAxis` block.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The accepted answer reduces the **number of points** and that's why you end up with less lines.